# HuffmanCode Java instance variable assigned a tree, remains empty

Tags: java, dictionary, huffman-code

I'm writing a traversal method for creating a HuffmanCode program, and for some reason the map I build in the traversal method won't assign to the instance variable `codeMap`. I've tested the processes of the methods with string outputs in console - the `traversal` builds the `tree` correctly, yet when I assign

```
`codeMap = traversal(root,s);`
```

in my constructor, the codeMap remains empty ; returns `true` when I test for

```
`codeMap.isEmpty()`.
```

Why won't `codeMap` accept the returned map? The `root` variable I'm using,`freqMap`, and the PriorityQueue also work correctly in the constructor. Here is my constructor/instance variables:

```
TreeNode root;
Map<Character,String> codeMap;
Map<Character,Double> freqMap;
HuffmanCode(Map<Character,Double> freqMap){
   this.freqMap = freqMap;
   PriorityQueue<TreeNode> queue = new PriorityQueue<TreeNode>(new NodeComparator());
   for(Map.Entry<Character,Double> entry : freqMap.entrySet()){
     TreeNode temp = new TreeNode(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue());
     queue.add(temp);
   }
   while(queue.size() > 1){
     TreeNode t1 = queue.remove();
     TreeNode t2 = queue.remove();
     TreeNode node = new TreeNode(t1.freq + t2.freq, t1, t2);
     queue.add(node);
   }
   root = queue.remove();
   String s = ""; 
   codeMap = traversal(root,s);
}
```

and my `traversal` method:

```
public Map<Character,String> traversal(TreeNode node, String s){
  Map<Character,String> tree = new TreeMap<Character,String>();
  if(!node.isLeaf()){
    traversal(node.left,s+"0");
    traversal(node.right,s+"1");
  }else{
    tree.put(node.letter,s);
  }
  return tree;
}
```

I don't get any errors in compile or runtime. If the `main` method is needed, let me know, but the problem is originating from this constructor. I've been working for several hours straight and can't find the reason why `codeMap` remains empty...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At each entry to `traversal()` you create a new `tree`. The only one that gets returned to the initial calling method will always be empty because at that level the node will never be a leaf node.

You must instantiate the tree once and pass it as an argument to the recursive method.